# Best method to pass value in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I am still new to MVC, so sorry if this is an obvious question:

I have a page where the user can choose one of several items. When they select one, they are taken to another form to fill in their details.

What is the best way to transfer that value to the form page?
I don't want the ID of the item in the second (form) pages URL.

so it's **/choose-your-item/** to **/redemption/** where the user sees what was selected, and fills the form in. The item selected is displayed, and shown in a hidden form.

I guess one option is to store in a session before the redirect, but was wondering if there was another option.

I am using MVC3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help others, this is how I resolved my issue of needing multiple buttons posting back, and wanting to pass a different Id each time.

I have a single form on the page, that posts back to my controller:

**The Form:**

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ChooseYourItem", "Item", FormMethod.Post))
        {
```

**And the code**

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult ChooseYourItem(string itemId)
    {
        TempData["ITEMID"] = itemId

        return RedirectToAction("Create", "Redemption");
    }
```

Then, inside the form, I create buttons whose name == "**itemId**", but has a different value each time.

**For example**

```
<strong>Item 1</strong>
<button value="123" name="itemid" id="btn1">Select</button>

<strong>Item 2</strong>
<button value="456" name="itemid" id="btn2">Select</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Darin Dimitrov's answer would be best if you don't need to do any additional processing before displaying the **/redemption/** page. If you do need to some additional processing, you're going to have to use the `TempDataDictionary` to pass data between actions. Values stored in the `TempDataDictionary` lasts for one request which allows for data to be passed between actions, as opposed to the values stored in the `ViewDataDictionary` which only can be passed from an action to a view. Here's an example below:

```
public ActionResult ChooseYourItem()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChooseYourItem(string chosenItem)
{
    TempData["ChosenItem"] = chosenItem;

    // Do some other stuff if you need to

    return RedirectToAction("Redemption");
}

public ActionResult Redemption()
{
    var chosenItem = TempData["ChosenItem"];

    return View(chosenItem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave this a go, but when I got to my redemption page, my TempData value was null.
I am calling the ActionResult with jQuery from a button click? Not sure if this is the correct/best way?

I was not able to do the redirect in the code (it didn't work, and I read that the redirects get ignored in AJAX post backs?), so did a window.transfer in the javascript.

I am guessing my TempData value expired?

What is the best way to call my ActionResult from the page? Each "item" is selected from a button

Thanks

Comment: @xTRUMANx OK, I have created my line as follows:
<a onclick="location.href='/item/ChooseYourItem?itemId=123'">Select</a>. in the item controller, I can set the TempData value, then do the RedirectToAction to my redemption page. The TempData value is then available on the redemption page.

So, it works, but I do want to make sure I've done this in a best practice manner? Cheers

Comment: @mp3duck: Best practice would be to navigate to the redemption page using a button that hits the an action with HTTPPost applied. Since you set this up with a link, I'm assuming you don't have the HTTPPost attribute applied to the method which sets the value into the TempDataDictionary which isn't standard practice. Oh, and if you wouldn't mind marking this as an answer if it worked for you. I wouldn't mind the rep ;)

Comment: @xTRUEMANx thanks for this info.. 
How should I go about setting up a button that POSTS to my ActionResult then?
Like I mentioned above, I need to POST the item ID back each time?

Comment: I'll have several items per page

Comment: @mp3duck: The chosen item will be a limited set of items decided by you right? How about making a form with radio boxes that post to the ActionMethod. The selected value of the radio button group can be the chosen item that is placed in the TempDataDictionary. If you'd like an example of the View code, I could edit my answer to show it. But you'll have to wait, I'm 10 minutes away from a class right now so I'll be responding in a couple of hours when I get back home.

Comment: @xTRUMANx having radio buttons doesn't fit wit the design of my page.
I have items, with a "select" button/link below each one. Click button/link, go to next page. I am therefore not able to select the item first, and then have a separate, single button to submit the form.

Comment: Then you'll need to wrap each button in a form tag so that it'll POST to the controller rather then do a GET request. Do you mind if we take this to email. Comments weren't designed for these sort of conversations. Email your current view to [myusername] at gmail dot com. I'll post the solution on my answer later so others can follow along as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the selected value in the url you could use form POST. So instead of redirecting to the new page, you could POST to it:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController"))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(...)
    <input type="submit" value="Go to details form" />
}
```